# form-inline class of bootstrap 4 is displaying the controls in two rows in IE and Edge

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have below markup in html using bootstrap 4 which is being displayed in single row while the same is getting broken into two in IE Edge

```
<form class="form-inline" style="margin-top:10px;">
<label for="text" class="mr-sm-2">HOUR</label>
input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="HOUR">
<label for="text" class="mr-sm-2">MINUTE</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="MINUTE">
<label for="text" class="mr-sm-2">SECONDS</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="SECONDS">

<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:20px;">
<button type="button" id="AMPM" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="width:160px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    AM/PM
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="SelectAMPM">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AM</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PM</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

How to display entire form in one row in Internet Explorer and Edge? What bootstrap 4 classes needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on my side and the form shows in one row in latest Edge and IE.

I wonder that what version of IE/Edge you've used to display two rows.

Besides, I would like to tell that when you use inline attribute the field goes from horizontal to vertical due to not enough space/width. You could see this from the link:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms.asp

I've modified parts of the style by using the class form-control.Maybe you could refer to.

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">HOUR</label>
        <input id="HOUR" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">MINUTE</label>
        <input id="MINUTE" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">SECONDS</label>
        <input id="SECONDS" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:20px;">
            <button type="button" id="AMPM" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="width:160px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                AM/PM
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="SelectAMPM">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AM</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PM</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: the result in IE and Edge]